# Javascript Keydown Not Triggering

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with getting the keydown of up arrow to trigger. I dont really understand what the problem with this is, most likely my messy formatting, but the keydown just doesn't trigger.

```html
<script>
  window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'ArrowUp') {
        close();
    window.open("https://bsd.instructure.com/?login_success=1");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: [keyboard events are document-level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), not window level.

Comment: Which basically means, use `document.addEventListener()`, not `window`. (Though reading through that documentation is a good idea if you haven't before.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) and [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) API.

JavaScript cannot open windows if the browser blocks them. I tried your code and it says:
"Firefox prevented this site from opening a pop-up window. [Options]".

You can only open windows user-generated (e.g. button / link click).
Your event is working fine, but the browser is preventing the pop-up window.

```js
window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  if (event.key == 'ArrowUp') {
    window.close(); // Blocked for certain standards
    window.open("https://bsd.instructure.com/?login_success=1"); // Blocked in the user's preferences
  }
});
```

I also recommend you use `document` events instead of `window`:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  if (event.key == 'ArrowUp') {
    // Action here
  }
});
```

You can use the window `location` property to navigate to pages.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  if (event.key == 'ArrowUp') {
    window.close();
    window.location.replace("https://bsd.instructure.com/?login_success=1");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for the sake of completeness. as @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans already answered the question correctly. bind the document object to the event instead of the window object.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {     
    if (event.key == 'ArrowUp') {
        console.log('Arrow UP');
        close();
    }
});
```